# Krull dimension of a quotient ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, irreducible-polynomials, krull-dimension

The question that I am about to ask can be trivial, even if so, I would be grateful for any useful answer.

> Why $\mathbb C[x,y]/\langle\pi^k\rangle$ is finite dimensional, where $\pi$ is some prime polynomial?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: It is not (try for example the polynomial $x$).

Comment: $\mathbb{C}[x,y]/x\cong\mathbb{C}[y]$ is not finite dimensional right? As to the Krull dimension $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ itself is already two dimensional. Can I conlclude the statement above like this? but what about the prime property of $p$?

Comment: So there's two questions you are asking. As Tobias showed, the quotient ring is not finite dimensional as a vector space. That is the case no matter what $p$ is On the other hand, since $\mathbb{C}[x, y]$ is itself finite Krull dimension, so is any quotient, again, no matter what $p$ is.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But one more thing, does the Krull dimension of the quotient above have to be less than two? or less than k?

Comment: Less than 2: a chain of prime ideals in a quotient ring corresponds to a chain of prime ideals in the original ring, where the prime ideals contain the ideal that is used to form the quotient.